# jquery click event not fired in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am re-posting this question cause I made some mistake in my question last time.

I am trying to do something when user clicks on label.

```
<label class="my-label"> ....
```

I am trying to get the click event fired It is working on chrome and safari but not working on IE 11.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".my-label").click(function(){
     ...
  });
});
```

I tried on, bind, live, but no success.

Comment: What version of IE? What version of jQuery?

Comment: Create jsfiddle or jsbin to prove that it is not firing.

Comment: Any errors in your console? Can you set a breakpoint in your function to see if maybe the actions within it are not working?

Comment: Also, ===> Enable JS in your IE : http://enable-javascript.com/ (just in case)

Comment: @j08691: jquery11.0, IE 11

Comment: If you make a mistake in your question, edit it instead of re-posting.